# How to delete a specified word in a txt file using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, replace

So i have this batch file that needs to delete a word in a txt file. it needs to delete the "addons" word at the end of this directory: D:\Batch Files\files\addons

Comment: Show us the batch-file, we won't write the whole code for you

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It will create a new file though.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("Test.txt") DO (
    Set "line=%%G" & echo !line:Pie=!
)>>"Test2.txt
```

Comment: you append to the same file, you are reading from. So it doubles your data. Better write to a new file (you can rename it afterwards, overwriting the original file, if needed)